# ¿Cómo puedo saber la imagen que está encima en un Carrousel de Materialize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Tengo una *label* que quiero cambiar cada vez que arrastro un [Carrousel de Materialize](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html) y una nueva imagen queda encima de todas.

Actualmente lo puedo hacer si le doy clic a la imagen:

```
[Utilizando (click)="selectStage('Volcano.jpg', 92)" por ejemplo]
```

Me gustaría que fuera aún más automático y se cambie el valor de la *label* con la imagen que quedó arriba del *Carrousel*.

Comment: ¿Has considerado usar el [Slider](http://materializecss.com/media.html) en lugar del `Carrousel`?

Answer (score 0):

La documentación es realmente mala para el carrousel de Materialize, o al menos falta que se complete bastante.

Te propongo algo no muy estético pero funciona.

**HTML**

```
<div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" data-titulo="Hormigas caminando"  href="#one!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" data-titulo="La costa tranquila" href="#two!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" data-titulo="Lago" href="#three!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" data-titulo="Arboleda seca" href="#four!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" data-titulo="Playa - atardecer" href="#five!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
</div>
<p style="text-align:center;margin-top:-80px;" id="seleccionado"></p>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.carousel').carousel();
      var ppal = "";

            setInterval(function(){revisar();},1500);      
      function revisar(){
          ppal = $('.carousel-item.active').attr("data-titulo");
          if (ppal != ""){$("#seleccionado").text(ppal);}      
      }
    });
```

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional.
https://jsfiddle.net/piojoman/s69n0sxq/3/

Comment: Muchas gracias. Terminé haciendo algo parecido.

Comment: NOTA: Esto sólo funciona en Materialize v0.98.0+.